# How to Disable "Re-start: Cold restart" Physical Button on Android Device

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, restart, rooted-device

I've searched high and low and can't not locate the Key name of the "Restart: Cold restart" button on an Android Rugged A9 Phone to disable it.

[image: photo of Android Rugged A9 phone with Cold restart button highlighted]

I'd like to disable this button as it's accidentally pressed frequently.

The device is Android version 4.4.2 rooted, However, within System>usr>Keylayout>Generic.kl I can not locate the name of the Key. Through research, I know that when I find the Key, all I have to do is input a "#" in front of the Key to disable it.

Can anyone please help me identify this Key? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you already solved this but if not look into the `/system/usr/keylayout/Generic.kl` file. You have to look for the specific key and then comment the line. It should be one that has to do with RESTART or REBOOT. For example in the YT3-850F tablet there's a line commented out that states:

```
#key 408 "KEY_RESTART"
```

In your `Generic.kl` file you should find one that is not commented out. Commenting a line in the `Generic.kl` file makes the system ignore the pressing of that specific key.